# HaarCascade (for OpenCV) to recognize a marker

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, marker

I'm trying to get OpenCV to recognize a visual badge (marker). Does anyone have an existing HaarCascade (preferably an xml file) of a badge of some sort?

Links of any sort are appreciated
Thx!
Antoine

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can create your own haar cascase using the following link:

http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html

I'm not aware of any existing haar xml which can recognize market/visual badge.